# Django Mysql Binary Log Error

Tags: mysql, django

I am using MySQL database. On updating data it gives me "unsafe statement of binary log" error.

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: The key part is _"on updating data"_ - how are you doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Warning Code 1592 Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925792/mysql-warning-code-1592-unsafe-statement-written-to-the-binary-log-using-stateme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can get rid of this issue from this solution.

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
FLUSH LOGS;
SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED';
FLUSH LOGS;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```