# Mysql warning when delete: Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format

Tags: mysql

My mysql delete statement is simple:

```
DELETE
FROM ts_template_size
WHERE template_id in
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM ts_template
    WHERE (id = 10153 OR style_type = 10153)
)
```

I got a warning:

> Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave.

I found another similar question in here: [Mysql Warning Code 1592 Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925792/mysql-warning-code-1592-unsafe-statement-written-to-the-binary-log-using-stateme) , but the statement in that question is `insert...select`. And as far as I understand, the problem occur in `insert` situation cuz the return rows in select query may have difference order in master and salve, and this may conduct the auto_increment column have different order when insert.

However, what I do is delete in table, the order is doesn't master, why I still get the warning message?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's your `DELETE` statement causing the warning?

Comment: @Phil , yes, absolute. There is auto-increment column both in `ts_template_size` and `ts_template` table